# Is there any data structure is java which has all the functionalities of lists in python

Tags: java

Does there exist any data structure in java which resembles lists In python he has the following characteristics-
Does not have fixed size
Can store multidimensional arrays within itself
Stores primitives as primitives. 
Has in built.methods to find element at given index, append or delete elements.etc

Comment: Look at `List` interface and `ArrayList` as the implementation of `List`  in `java.util`.

Comment: Currently no Java collection is able to store primitives as primitives.  They all must be promoted to objects.

Comment: Install jython. Use python lists in your Java code. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Store primitives as primitives? I don't think Python does not have primitives neither.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Java collections like Vector or Stack they provide unlimited size and GetItemAt(),add() and ...
this site explains the functions of each one . 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm